# why is it removing the 8th spot in the line where you change the number?

Tags: python

run it and see for yourself. 
it also won't let me choose the 8th spot

```
w, h = 8, 8;
Matrix = [["#" for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)] 


for w in Matrix:
    for h in w:       
     print("#",end = " ")
    print()




numA = int(input())
numB = int(input())

Matrix[numA - 1].pop(numB - 1)
Matrix[numA - 1][numB - 1] = J = 1

for w in Matrix:
   for h in w:    
    if h == "#":    
          print("#",end = " ")
    else:
          print("@",end = " ")
   print()
```

what's wrong with the code? it's in python 3.7 and run on notepad++ on windows if that's useful

Comment: You are popping (removing) an index, then trying to assign to it immediately after.

Comment: could it be because in numbering Python starts with 0?